# Running afplay in Mac sh well running rest of script?

Tags: bash, macos, shell, audio

I'm making an animation for a game in the Mac OS shell, and I'd like it to play music. Therefore, I (attempting to) take advantage of Mac OS' afplay feature, which plays a sound file such as an mp3 file directly from the shell. This is an example of my code:

```
afplay ~/music.mp3
echo "THE YEAR IS 2020"
clear
echo
echo "THE YEAR IS 2020"
clear
echo
echo
echo "THE YEAR IS 2020"
clear
```

However, in the `afplay ~/music.mp3` line, it just sits at a blank screen. Is there a way for it to play sound and run the rest of the script simultaneously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A command can be made to run in the background by tagging an & (ampersand) on the end. In the case of `afplay` there's also some info printed to screen. The help file doesn't show how this can be disabled, so the more hackish solution is to just redirect it do /dev/null.

```
afplay ~/music.mp3 &>/dev/null &
echo "THE YEAR IS 2020"

echo "THE YEAR IS 2020"

echo "THE YEAR IS 2020"
```

Oh, and to stop the music plaing, run `kill $!`. `$!` is a special variable and contains the PID of the most recent background process.

Comment: Is there any alternative ways to kill the process?

Comment: You can stop it more gently by sending a 'terminal stop' signal `kill -TSTP $!`, which is equivalent to pressing Ctrl-Z to stop a foreground process. If you do this you can then run `kill -CONT $!` to resume the process.